# How can I get the selected item text or position in a MaterialBetterSpinner?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am using MaterialBetterSpinner.
How can I get the selected item text or position?

Every time I get the same flag.
What can I do?

I want to send this flag to server and get response according to it.
Each time it sends `flag_check=1;`

```
ArrayList<String> morning_evening_flag = new     ArrayList <String>();


                morning_evening_flag.add("Morning");
                morning_evening_flag.add("Evening");

 ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,R.layout.spinner_row, morning_evening_flag);
                    final MaterialBetterSpinner spinner1 = (MaterialBetterSpinner) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                    spinner1.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter1);
                            int morning_pasition=spinnerAdapter1.getPosition("Morning");

                int Evening_pasition=spinnerAdapter1.getPosition("Evening");

                Log.e("morning_pasition", morning_pasition+"");
                Log.e("Evening_pasition", Evening_pasition+"");
                final int flag_check;
                if("Morning".equals("0"))
                {
                    flag_check=0;
                }
                else
                    flag_check=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the onClickListener to the spinner as:

> spinnerName.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

And now implement the onItemselected method

```
@Override 
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // You will get the position and selected item here
}
```